# Can a bare repository have an index? Is this a bug?

Tags: git, gitpython

I'm trying to get [GitPython 0.3](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3/index.html) to commit a file to a repository. Roughly, I'm doing this as follows:

```
data = ...
istream = repo.odb.store(gitdb.IStream(git.Blob.type, len(data), StringIO(data)))
entry = git.BaseIndexEntry((stat.S_IFREG | 0644, istream.binsha, 0, path))
index = git.IndexFile.from_tree(repo, repo.heads['master'])
index.add([entry])
index.commit(commit_message)
```

With a non-bare repository, this works as expected. Note that I'm never touching the filesystem explicitly, only Git's object database.

With a bare repository, however, this does not work: the `IndexFile.add` function is decorated with the `git_working_dir` decorator:

```
@git_working_dir
def add(self, items, force=True, fprogress=lambda *args: None, path_rewriter=None, 
            write=True):
    """Add files from the working tree, specific blobs or BaseIndexEntries
    to the index.
```

This decorator tries to chdir to the repo's `working_tree_dir`, so that path references can be resolved correctly. However, `working_tree_dir` is not valid for a bare repository, raising an `AssertionError`.

Does anyone have an idea why this decorator is here? Is it just for path resolving, or is it impossible to create an index in a bare repository? Is this a bug in GitPython, or in my understanding of Git?

---

Edit: Similarly, the `IndexFile.remove` function asserts (via the `default_index` decorator) that we are the default index. Bare repositories certainly don't have a default index, but can they have no index objects at all?

```
@post_clear_cache
@default_index
def remove(self, items, working_tree=False, **kwargs):
    """Remove the given items from the index and optionally from
    the working tree as well.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer inspection of the `IndexFile.add` function, I realized that I need only very little of its functionality. In fact, just replacing the `add` call by these two lines does the trick:

```
index.entries[index.entry_key(entry)] = git.IndexEntry.from_base(entry)
index.write()
```

I'm still wondering whether this is a good idea, though...

Comment: i would say that's fine. you don't need to "stage" changes if you are going to send those blobs directly in the bare repo anyways.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API reference](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3/reference.html):

> git.index.util.git_working_dir(func)
>
> Decorator which changes the current working dir to the one of the git repository in order to assure relative paths are handled correctly

Bare Git repositories don't have a working directory, so the `add` function is getting hung up on this.

However, a bare Git repo also doesn't have an index [[1]](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2007/7/14/251527).

Comment: It doesn't have a *default* index, for sure, because there's no HEAD to create it from. However, I'm not certain that a bare repo cannot contain index objects, per se.

Comment: i *have* seen an index in a bare repo here.

Comment: You certainly can create an index on a bare repo: `git init --bare . && git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 $(echo foo | git hash-object -t blob -w --stdin) test.txt && git write-tree` creates a tree object containing one file using the index.